# How would you differentiate between the two in reported speech?

Tags: reported-speech

His father said,"It's time you visited your uncle". and

His father said,"It's time you visited my uncle".

I think the reported speech for both the sentences would be

His father said that it was time he visited his uncle.

Comment: In *His father said that it was time he visited his uncle* we can't know without additional context whether "he" and "his" refer to father or to son.  Father can say to son: "It's time *I* visited my uncle" and that could be reported "His father said it was time he visited his uncle".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is genuinely ambiguous, and there's no simple way to distinguish the meanings.

In writing, you tend to get things like

> His father said that it was time that he visited his (Michael's own) uncle.

vs

> His father said that it was time that he visited his (the father's) uncle.

Even saying "his own" doesn't clarify, as that could still be either of them.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the sentence would not be said in thin air or a vacuum. In other words there would be a context and perhaps a discourse underway which would help to if not absolutely disambiguate the sentence.